# Multi-index dataframe from sequence of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Say I have a list of dataframes `[df1, df2, df3]`, where each single dataframe looks as follows:

```
> df1 

            median   std
control        0.4   0.2
experiment     0.2   0.3
```

How can I create a **multi-index** dataframe that stitches them together? Like this:

```
                         df1                 df2                  df3
          control experiment  control experiment  control  experiment
median        0.4        0.2      ...       ...      ...          ...
std           0.2        0.3      ...       ...      ...          ...
```

Comment: Your column and index labels are also switched. Is this also the question?

Comment: Thanks @joris. I am all set. I can `.T` the resulting multi-index dataframe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So you can provide the dataframes as a dict (as in duplicate question: [python/pandas: how to combine two dataframes into one with hierarchical column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989281/python-pandas-how-to-combine-two-dataframes-into-one-with-hierarchical-column-i/15990537#15990537)), and then the dict keys are used:

```
pd.concat({'df1':df1, 'df2':df2, 'df3':df3}, axis=1)
```

or another option is to use the `keys` keyword argument:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])
```