# How to simply add a column level to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

let say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcde'), data={'A': range(5), 'B': range(5)})
 df
Out[92]: 
   A  B
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
```

Asumming that this dataframe already exist, how can I simply add a level 'C' to the column index so I get this:

```
 df
Out[92]: 
   A  B
   C  C
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
```

I saw SO anwser like this [python/pandas: how to combine two dataframes into one with hierarchical column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989281/python-pandas-how-to-combine-two-dataframes-into-one-with-hierarchical-column-i) but this concat different dataframe instead of adding a column level to an already existing dataframe.

-

Answer (score 150, accepted):

As suggested by @StevenG himself, a better answer:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.columns.levels + [['C']])

print(df)
#    A  B
#    C  C
# a  0  0
# b  1  1
# c  2  2
# d  3  3
# e  4  4
```

Comment: this is great, I like `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['C']])` which is a bite more trivial since you don't have to keep track of the `len` of `df.columns`. you mind adding it to the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @StevenG great I did not know this trick. Thanks I have learned something new :-)

Comment: Do you have any tips, how to add another level, when the original df already has multiindex column names? I tried to add new level with from_product() method, however I received this error message: 'NotImplementedError: isnull is not defined for MultiIndex'.

Comment: @LenkaVraná `pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.columns.levels + [['C']])`

Comment: @user3556757 this unfortunately did not work for me (unhashable type 'index' or 'list')

Comment: EDIT: got it with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.Index(['C'])] + df.columns.levels)`  (my order is inversed) (don't know what went wrong)

Comment: For anyone. I found casting the existing columns index to list before using it in MultiIndex.from_product works for 'isna not implemented'. `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(df.columns), ['C']])`

Comment: Although you then have to flatten the indices. You could use `pd.concat([df], keys=[<value>], names=['<level_name>'],axis=1)` for the same result.

Comment: Can this be done for One column only? like this for example#    A  B
           C
# a  0  0
# b  1  1
# c  2  2
# d  3  3
# e  4  4

Comment: Fastest (or at least tied) of all the answers I tested, and easiest to read.

Comment: Get an error of `*** AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'levels'`

Answer (score 32):

***option 1***
***`set_index` and `T`***

```
df.T.set_index(np.repeat('C', df.shape[1]), append=True).T
```

***option 2***
***`pd.concat`, `keys`, and `swaplevel`***

```
pd.concat([df], axis=1, keys=['C']).swaplevel(0, 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks did not know about swap and this is convinient. I tested it for a large dataframe to see if it was more efficient than setting `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['C']])` and it was about 25% slower.

Comment: No surprises!  Romain's answer is quicker.  I added this because I think it's valuable to know.

Comment: `pd.concat([df], axis=1, keys=['C'])` worked very well for multilevel columns

Comment: Option 2 should be the accepted answer for the general case when `df.columns` can be a `pd.MultiIndex`.

Comment: The `pd.concat` answer is great because it doesn't modify the original df.

Comment: Always watch out with .T since it can cause some disruption to well-typed columns. In general .T-.T transformations are lossy.
Using seaborn, take `df = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")` and compare `df.info()` and `df.T.T.info()`; all columns turn into object and memory usage grows five times!

Answer (score 18):

A solution which adds a name to the new level and is easier on the eyes than other answers already presented:

```
df['newlevel'] = 'C'
df = df.set_index('newlevel', append=True).unstack('newlevel')

print(df)
#           A  B
# newlevel  C  C
# a         0  0
# b         1  1
# c         2  2
# d         3  3
# e         4  4
```

Comment: This is short and works also with columns that are already multi-level! As a one liner: `df.assign(newlevel='C').set_index('newlevel', append=True).unstack('newlevel')`.

Comment: If the dataframe has very many rows, this has a per-row cost which is unnecessary

Answer (score 13):

You could just assign the columns like:

```
>>> df.columns = [df.columns, ['C', 'C']]
>>> df
   A  B
   C  C
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
>>>
```

Or for unknown length of columns:

```
>>> df.columns = [df.columns.get_level_values(0), np.repeat('C', df.shape[1])]
>>> df
   A  B
   C  C
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
>>>
```

Comment: This is the way, when you want to be flexible and assign any list as the new level

Answer (score 9):

Another way for MultiIndex (appanding `'E'`):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(lambda x: (x[0], 'E', x[1]), df.columns))

   A  B
   E  E
   C  D
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
```

Comment: A shorter version: `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c[0], 'E', c[1]) for c in df.columns])`

Answer (score 6):

I like it explicit (using `MultiIndex`) and chain-friendly (`.set_axis`):

```
df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, ['C']]), axis=1)
```

This is particularly convenient when merging DataFrames with different column level numbers, where Pandas (1.4.2) raises a FutureWarning (`FutureWarning: merging between different levels is deprecated and will be removed ...` ):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcde'), data={'A': range(5), 'B': range(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcde'), data=range(10, 15), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("C", "x")]))

# df1:
   A  B
a  0  0
b  1  1

# df2:
    C
    x
a  10
b  11

# merge while giving df1 another column level:
pd.merge(df1.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['']]), axis=1),
         df2, 
         left_index=True, right_index=True)

# result:
   A  B   C
          x
a  0  0  10
b  1  1  11
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, but using a list comprehension of tuples as the arg to pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples():

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col, 'C') for col in df.columns])

df
   A  B
   C  C
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a dedicated function for this. It less elegant, but more flexible. The advantages:

- automatically handles `Index` and `MultiIndex`
- can assign name
- can add multiple level at once
- choose location (top or bottom)

Best regards.

```
def addLevel(index, value='', name=None, n=1, onTop=False):
    """Add extra dummy levels to index"""
    assert isinstance(index, (pd.MultiIndex, pd.Index))
    xar = np.array(index.tolist()).transpose()
    names = index.names if isinstance(index, pd.MultiIndex) else [index.name]
    addValues = np.full(shape=(n, xar.shape[-1]), fill_value=value)
    addName = [name] * n

    if onTop:
        names = addName + names
        xar = np.vstack([addValues, xar])
    else:
        names = names + addName
        xar = np.vstack([xar, addValues])

    return pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(xar, names=names)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abc'), data={'A': range(3), 'B': range(3)})
df.columns = addLevel(df.columns, value='C')
df.columns = addLevel(df.columns, value='D', name='D-name')
df.columns = addLevel(df.columns, value='E2', n=2)
df.columns = addLevel(df.columns, value='Top', name='OnTop', onTop=True)
df.columns = addLevel(df.columns, value=1, name='Number')
print(df)
## OnTop  Top   
##          A  B
##          C  C
## D-name   D  D
##         E2 E2
##         E2 E2
## Number   1  1
## a        0  0
## b        1  1
## c        2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an exhaustive way to do it, so here it is:

```py
def add_multindex_level(
        data: pd.DataFrame,
        keys: Union[Any, List[Any]],
        level: int=0,
        axis: int=0,
        name: str=None,
        inplace: bool=False,
    ) -> pd.DataFrame:

    to_promote = data.columns if axis==1 else data.index
    keys = [keys]*len(to_promote) if isinstance(keys, str) else keys
    if len(keys)!=len(to_promote):
        raise ValueError(
            "Keys must be a value or array-like matching the length of the index to extend"
        )

    new_keys = []
    for existing_key,insert_key in zip(to_promote, keys):
        if isinstance(existing_key, tuple):
            new_key = (*existing_key[:level], insert_key, *existing_key[level:])
        else:
            new_key = (existing_key, insert_key) if level else (insert_key, existing_key)
        new_keys.append(new_key)

    data_ = data if inplace else data.copy(deep=True)
    new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_keys)

    new_names = []
    for l in range(new_index.nlevels):
        if l==level:
            n = name
        else:
            n = to_promote.names[l - (1 if l>=level else 0)]
        new_names.append(n)

    new_index.names = new_names

    if axis:
        data_.columns = new_index
    else:
        data_.index = new_index

    return None if inplace else data_

>>> source
   a  b  c
0  0  5  0
1  1  6  1
2  0  9  4

>>> add_multindex_level(source, ['x','y','z'], level=1, axis=1)
   a  b  c
   x  y  z
0  0  5  0
1  1  6  1
2  0  9  4

>>> add_multindex_level(source, ['x','y','z'], level=0, axis=1)
   x  y  z
   a  b  c
0  0  5  0
1  1  6  1
2  0  9  4

>>> add_multindex_level(source, 'A', level=0, axis=1)
   x  y  z
   A  A  A
0  0  5  0
1  1  6  1
2  0  9  4

>>> add_multindex_level(source, 'A', level=0, axis=0)
      x  y  z
A  0  0  5  0
A  1  1  6  1
A  2  0  9  4
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted and other high score answers haven't coped with multi-index df.
I write this function to to add a value or list to specific level with custom name :

```
from typing import Iterable

def add_level(df, vals, name='', level=0):
    cols = df.columns
    if not isinstance(vals, Iterable):
        vals = np.repeat(vals, cols.shape[0])
    else:
        assert cols.shape[0]%len(vals) == 0, 'cols.shape[0] must be divisible by len(vals)'
        vals = np.repeat(vals.to_list(), cols.shape[0]//len(vals))

    new_names = list(cols.names)
    new_names.insert(level, name)

    new_cols_df = cols.to_frame().assign(**{name:vals})
    new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(new_cols_df[new_names])
    
    df1 = df.copy()
    df1.columns = new_cols
    return df1
```

Preview:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only use this line:

```
df.columns = [df.columns, ['C'] * len(df.columns)]
```