# adding list in a new column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new column with a set of datas for each line of a specific column, creating a breakdown to the first level. e.g:

```
 Level
   1
   2
   3

 Level  Breakdown
   1
           a
           b
           c
           d
   2   
           a
           b
           c
           d
   3
           a
           b
           c
           d
```

any hints how do I code this breakdown on pandas dataframe?

I understand that Multiindex must have an array to match with the 'Breakdown'. But the dataframe has more than 10 thousand registers, how can I combine my tuples with this amount of range?

In fact, I've got a raw database that I have to rearrange like a schedule format. Hereunder, I can share a small sample:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mRGA.png)

So, I would like to rearrange the database in this format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8IQZ.png)

Comment: Adding some sample data would be very helpful.

Comment: Long shot but have you tried setting level 1 as an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this with [Multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

But you will need an extra index for a,b,c,d

```
arrays = [["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3"],
      ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]] 
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Levels','Breakdown'])

s = pandas.DataFrame("your_data", index=index)
```

With the data used in the documentation your dataframe would look like:

```
Levels Breakdown          
1      a         -0.985654
       b          0.782516
       c         -0.896590
2      a          0.841488
       b         -0.577790
       c         -1.130534
       a          0.587779
3      b         -0.935374
       c          1.658043
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since you edited your question I have come up with a sulotion.
For details check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225683/how-to-simply-add-a-column-level-to-a-pandas-dataframe) 
and the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) on pandas.DataFrame.stack.

Since you only posted pictures instead of copying data I didn't use your values. But my sample data looks like this:

```
d = {"Line": ["foo", "bar", "baz"], "CUT START": ["a", "b", "c"], 
"CUT FINISH": ["x", "y", "z"],
"END START" :[1, 2, 3], "END FINISH": [4, 5, 6]}

   Line   CUT START CUT FINISH  END START  END FINISH
0  foo         a          x          1           4
1  bar         b          y          2           5
2  baz         c          z          3           6
```

I transformed it like this:

```
# Set line as index
df = df.set_index("Line")

activitys = ["CUT", "END"]  # Add the rest of your activitys here
status = ["START", "FINISH"]

df.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([activitys, status])
```

This returns:

```
           CUT          END       
     START FINISH START FINISH
Line                          
foo      a      x     1      4
bar      b      y     2      5
baz      c      z     3      6
```

Then you can stack.

```
df = df.stack(0)

         FINISH START
Line                 
foo  CUT      x     a
     END      4     1
bar  CUT      y     b
     END      5     2
baz  CUT      z     c
     END      6     3
```

Now you only need to reorder

```
df.columns = ["START", "FINISH"]
```

Comment: the code worked just fine. the key is to set the main column as an index and all data will come along. Thank you very much!