# Is possible to add a new level on columns on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I add a level in a data frame?
from:

```
x  2002  2003 2004
a   1      2    3  
b   1      2    3
c   1      2    3
```

To:

```
       year
x  2002  2003 2004
a   1      2    3  
b   1      2    3
c   1      2    3
```

Comment: can this be useful? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: You may do this:                                                                                            # Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','b','c'], '2002':[1,1,1], '2003':[2,2,2], '2004':[3,3,3]})
# Set column x to index
df = df.set_index('x')
# create new column object with 2 dimenisons (multi column index)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['year'] * 3, df.columns])
# assign new column object as columns
df.columns= cols
# reset index so that 'x' becomes level 1 column name
df=df.reset_index()
print(df)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a duplicate of [How to simply add a column level to a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225683/how-to-simply-add-a-column-level-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

First create the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = ["a", "b", "c"]
cols = [2002, 2003, 2004]
val1 = [1, 1, 1]
val2 = [2, 2, 2]
val3 = [3, 3, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame([val1, val2, val3], columns=cols, index=idx)
```

Then you can do:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['years'], df.columns])
```