# Append new level to DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame, how can I add a new level to the columns based on an iterable given by the user? In other words, how do I append a new level?

The question [How to simply add a column level to a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225683/how-to-simply-add-a-column-level-to-a-pandas-dataframe) shows how to add a new level given a single value, so it doesn't cover this case.

Here is the expected behaviour:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=["A", "B"], index=range(2))
>>> df
    A   B
0   0   0
1   0   0
>>> append_level(df, ["C", "D"])
    A   B
    C   D
0   0   0
1   0   0
```

The solution should also work with MultiIndex columns, so

```
>>> append_level(append_level(df, ["C", "D"]), ["E", "F"])
    A   B
    C   D
    E   F
0   0   0
1   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns is not multiindex, you can just do:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.tolist(), ['C','D']])
```

If its multiindex:

```py
if isinstance(df.columns, pd.MultiIndex):
     df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([*df.columns.levels, ['E', 'F']])
```

The [`pd.MultiIndex.levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.levels.html#) gives a Frozenlist of level values and you need to unpack to form the list of lists as input to from_arrays

Comment: Thanks @SomeDude, the solution works with single column dataframes but gives the wrong result if the dataframe has a multi index column. I have edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
def append_level(df, new_level):
    new_df = df.copy()
    new_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(*zip(*df.columns), new_level))
    return new_df
```